# How to show organization chart in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-foundation

How to show organization chart for a company in intranet portal without using any third party web part? what is the simplest way to show data correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is out-of-the-box functionality included with "MySite". You will need to have the User Profile Service set up though. See these links:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-my-site-HA010108748.aspx

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-SharePoint-to-Build-an-Org-Chart-The-Options.aspx

Comment: This is not working when used in any other non-MySite, it does require  http://www.tcscblog.com/2011/04/11/using-the-sharepoint-2010-organization-browser-in-another-web-application/ and it also depends on AD structure, and having Manager property setup